# How to combine into single attribute if metadata is same?

Tags: xml, powershell, msbuild, powershell-2.0, msbuild-4.0

I am having Msbuild XML file like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <Project xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
         <ItemGroup>
             <Notifications Include="someone@gmail.com"/>
         </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup> 
         <Xcopy Include="..\..\..\Release\UtilitiesAssembly.dll"> 
             <Destination>"..\..\..\Mycomponent\depl\BOM\Folder1</Destination> 
         </Xcopy>
         <Xcopy Include="..\..\..\Release\Core.assembly.dll">
             <Destination>"..\..\..\Mycomponent\depl\BOM\Folder1</Destination>
         </Xcopy>
         <Xcopy Include="..\..\..\Release\UIAssembly.dll"> 
             <Destination>"..\..\..\Anothercomponent\Folder1</Destination> 
         </Xcopy>
         <Xcopy Include="..\..\..\Release\Core.assembly.dll">
             <Destination>"..\..\..\Anothercomponent\depl\BOM</Destination>
         </Xcopy>
    </Itemgroup>
  </Project>
```

Actually i would like to group XCopy Itemgroup like this

```
      <Xcopy Include="..\..\..\Release\UtilitiesAssembly.dll;
                    ..\..\..\Release\\Core.assembly.dll;">
      <Destination>"..\..\..\Mycomponent\depl\BOM\Folder1</Destination>
     </Xcopy>

     <Xcopy Include="..\..\..\Release\UIAssembly.dll;">
      <Destination>"..\..\..\Anothercomponent\Folder1</Destination>
     </Xcopy>

     <Xcopy Include="..\..\..\Release\Core.assembly.dll">
             <Destination>"..\..\..\Anothercomponent\depl\BOM</Destination>
     </Xcopy>
```

How to achieve it using Powershell or Msbuild or by some other mechanism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example how to do this using the `Group-Object` cmdlet. It will group the xcopy elements by `Destination` and combine the `Include` paths into a semi-colon separated string. The output is stored in a new XML document and saved to disk. This doesn't programatically update the original. You can just copy paste the new consolidated XML over you original XML.

*Update* Now that I see your whole file, I see it has a default namespace which causes problems with XPath. There are two ways to get around this problem.

1. Use [namespace agnostic xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953280/namespace-agnostic-xpath-query-with-element-content)
2. Use a namespace manager

Here is an updated example using namespace agnostic xpath. Also in order to get the indentation you are looking for we'll need to do some text file processing after the XML object processing.

```
$xml="Myinput.xml"
$tempXmlFile = "C:\New.xml"

$outXml = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$outXml.AppendChild($outXml.CreateElement("root")) > $null

$x = [xml] (Get-Content $xml)
$x.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='Xcopy']") | Group-Object Destination | % {
    $includePaths = ($_.Group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Include) -join ";"
    $element = $outXml.CreateElement("Xcopy")
    $element2 = $outXml.CreateElement("Destination")
    $element2.InnerText = $_.Name
    $element.AppendChild($element2) > $null
    $element.SetAttribute("Include", $includePaths)
    $outXml.DocumentElement.AppendChild($element) > $null
}
$outXml.Save($tempXmlFile)

$data = Get-Content $tempXmlFile | % {
    $search = 'Include="'
    $index = $_.IndexOf('Include="')
    if ($index -gt 0) { 
        $spaces = ( ' ' * ($index + $search.length) ) 
    }
    $_ -replace ';', ";`n${spaces}"
}
$data | Set-Content $tempXmlFile
& notepad $tempXmlFile
```

Creates output:

```
<root>
  <Xcopy Include="..\..\..\Release\UtilitiesAssembly.dll
                  ..\..\..\Release\Core.assembly.dll">
    <Destination>"..\..\..\Mycomponent\depl\BOM\Folder1</Destination>
  </Xcopy>
  <Xcopy Include="..\..\..\Release\UIAssembly.dll">
    <Destination>"..\..\..\Anothercomponent\Folder1</Destination>
  </Xcopy>
  <Xcopy Include="..\..\..\Release\Core.assembly.dll">
    <Destination>"..\..\..\Anothercomponent\depl\BOM</Destination>
  </Xcopy>
</root>
```

Comment: I am getting following issue buddy. Cannot convert value "E:\Powershellscripts\Comp1.Targets" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

Comment: My input file looks like below "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"> <ItemGroup><ComponentNotifications Include="someone@gmail.com"/></ItemGroup> <ItemGroup> <Xcopy Include="..\..\..\Release\UtilitiesAssembly.dll">
      <Destination>"..\..\..\Mycomponent\depl\BOM\Folder1</Destination>
    </Xcopy>
    <Xcopy Include="..\..\..\Release\Core.assembly.dll">
      <Destination>"..\..\..\Mycomponent\depl\BOM\Folder1</Destination>
    </Xcopy></Itemgroup>

Comment: If Get-content $xml is replaced with $xml , i got the same error i faced. So i have edited the answer. Thanks buddy.

Comment: @Samselvaprabu Woops I was testing a little differently by putting your source XML in a here string. I copied my update into the answer without re-adjusting it for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from MSBuild 3.5 you can use [**ItemDefinitionGroup**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb651788.aspx).

```
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <Xcopy>
      <Destination>"..\..\..\Mycomponent\depl\BOM\Folder1</Destination>
    </Xcopy>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Xcopy Include="..\..\..\Release\UtilitiesAssembly.dll" />
    <Xcopy Include="..\..\..\Release\Core.assembly.dll" />
    <Xcopy Include="..\..\..\Release\UIAssembly.dll;">
      <Destination>"..\..\..\Anothercomponent\Folder1</Destination>     
    </Xcopy>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I think Itemdefinitiongroup would work if it has common metadata for all. It is a useful information. I have added clarity to my question further. Will it work for this case?