# PowerShell changes return object's type

Tags: function, powershell, powershell-3.0, return-type, powershell-ise

I am using PowerShell v3 and the Windows PowerShell ISE.  I have the following function that works fine:

```
function Get-XmlNode([xml]$XmlDocument, [string]$NodePath, [string]$NamespaceURI = "", [string]$NodeSeparatorCharacter = '.')
{
    # If a Namespace URI was not given, use the Xml document's default namespace.
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($NamespaceURI)) { $NamespaceURI = $XmlDocument.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI }   

    # In order for SelectSingleNode() to actually work, we need to use the fully qualified node path along with an Xml Namespace Manager, so set them up.
    [System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager]$xmlNsManager = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($XmlDocument.NameTable)
    $xmlNsManager.AddNamespace("ns", $NamespaceURI)

    [string]$fullyQualifiedNodePath = Get-FullyQualifiedXmlNodePath -NodePath $NodePath -NodeSeparatorCharacter $NodeSeparatorCharacter

    # Try and get the node, then return it. Returns $null if the node was not found.
    $node = $XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode($fullyQualifiedNodePath, $xmlNsManager)
    return $node
}
```

Now, I will be creating a few similar functions, so I want to break the first 3 lines out into a new function so that I don't have to copy-paste them everywhere, so I have done this:

```
function Get-XmlNamespaceManager([xml]$XmlDocument, [string]$NamespaceURI = "")
{
    # If a Namespace URI was not given, use the Xml document's default namespace.
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($NamespaceURI)) { $NamespaceURI = $XmlDocument.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI }   

    # In order for SelectSingleNode() to actually work, we need to use the fully qualified node path along with an Xml Namespace Manager, so set them up.
    [System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager]$xmlNsManager = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($XmlDocument.NameTable)
    $xmlNsManager.AddNamespace("ns", $NamespaceURI)
    return $xmlNsManager
}

function Get-XmlNode([xml]$XmlDocument, [string]$NodePath, [string]$NamespaceURI = "", [string]$NodeSeparatorCharacter = '.')
{
    [System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager]$xmlNsManager = Get-XmlNamespaceManager -XmlDocument $XmlDocument -NamespaceURI $NamespaceURI
    [string]$fullyQualifiedNodePath = Get-FullyQualifiedXmlNodePath -NodePath $NodePath -NodeSeparatorCharacter $NodeSeparatorCharacter

    # Try and get the node, then return it. Returns $null if the node was not found.
    $node = $XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode($fullyQualifiedNodePath, $xmlNsManager)
    return $node
}
```

The problem is that when "return $xmlNsManager" executes the following error is thrown:

```
Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager".
```

So even though I have explicitly cast my $xmlNsManager variables to be of type System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager, when it gets returned from the Get-XmlNamespaceManager function PowerShell is converting it to an Object array.

If I don't explicitly cast the value returned from the Get-XmlNamespaceManager function to System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager, then the following error is thrown from the .SelectSingleNode() function because the wrong data type is being passed into the function's 2nd parameter.

```
Cannot find an overload for "SelectSingleNode" and the argument count: "2".
```

So for some reason PowerShell is not maintaining the data type of the return variable.  I would really like to get this working from a function so that I don't have to copy-paste those 3 lines all over the place.  Any suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: So what have you got against the built-in `Select-Xml` cmdlet?  Using namespaces with it is as simple as passing it a hashtable of prefix to namespace mappings e.g. `$xml | Select-Xml -XPath '//dns:foo' -namespace @{dns='http://schema.foo.org'}`

Comment: Thanks Keith, I actually hadn't heard of the Select-Xml cmdlet. I would prefer to ignore the Xml Namespace all together as I don't care about it, but unfortunately .SelectSingleNode() requires it, as I discuss in my blog post (http://blog.danskingdom.com/powershell-functions-to-get-an-xml-node-and-get-and-set-an-xml-elements-value-even-when-the-element-does-not-already-exist/). Would using Select-Xml get around this problem?

Comment: `Select-Xml` is just calling either `SelectSingleNode` or `SelectNodes` (of XmlDocument) under the covers so it's still susceptible to XML namespaces which is why @Keith used the `-namespace` parameter.

Comment: By the way there IS a way to ignore XML namespaces altogether, you just have to write your Xpath differently. [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953280/namespace-agnostic-xpath-query-with-element-content) shows how.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What's happening is PowerShell is converting your namespace manager object to a string array.

I think it has to do with PowerShell's nature of "unrolling" collections when sending objects down the pipeline. I think PowerShell will do this for any type implementing IEnumerable (has a GetEnumerator method).

As a work around you can use the comma trick to prevent this behavior and send the object as a whole collection.

```
function Get-XmlNamespaceManager([xml]$XmlDocument, [string]$NamespaceURI = "")
{
    ...
    $xmlNsManager.AddNamespace("ns", $NamespaceURI)
    return ,$xmlNsManager
}
```

Comment: Yup, XmlNamespaceManager implements IEnumerable so PowerShell sees that as a sequence of items. Using the comma operator is how you fix this particular issue but the use of `return` is really unnecessary in this case (last line of function so no need for early return).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation guys. Keith, I'm traditionally a C# and .Net programmer who has only recently got into PowerShell, so I still have a habit of using return; also I like that it makes it explicit/obvious what the function is returning back.

Comment: @deadlydog Another gotcha (besides this unrolling thing) is that anything that returns a value that is not set to a variable or piped to null will be returned from your function, e.g. if you call XmlDocument.[AppendChild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild.aspx) method, it will return an XmlNode object which will be sent along with your namespace manager object unless you prevent it.

Comment: @AndyArismendi +1.  That is why I usually avoid return, except when I need to bail early on a function. Even then I tend not to use the `return <expr>` form.  It gives a false sense of what's being returned from the function.

Comment: @AndyArismendi You can also cast to void to suppress output from a method or Cmdlet, i.e. `[void] $xmlNsManager.AddNamespace("ns", $NamespaceURI)`.

Comment: @JamieSee `[void]` and `Out-Null` remove unnecessary function output, although what's happening here is `$xmlNsManager` (which a `System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager` type) implements IEnumerable (has `GetEnumerator()`) so Powershell is returning what it enumerates in an object array (`[System.Object[]`) rather than the XmlNamespaceManager object itself which is what OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

More specifically, what is happening here is that your coding habit of strongly typing $fullyQualifiedModePath is trying to turn the result of the Get (which is a list of objects) into a string.

[string]$foo

will constrain the variable $foo to only be a string, no matter what came back.  In this case, your type constraint is what is subtly screwing up the return and making it Object[]

Also, looking at your code, I would personally recommend you use Select-Xml (built into V2 and later), rather than do a lot of hand-coded XML unrolling.  You can do namespace queries in Select-Xml with -Namespace @{x="..."}.

Comment: The `$fullyQualifiedModePath` line isn't the one he's having an issue with. It's this one `[System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager]$xmlNsManager =`