# Return [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential] from a function

Tags: powershell, credentials

This question has kind of been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498320/powershell-changes-return-objects-type), but the "comma trick", mentioned by @Andy Arismendi doesn't work for me.

In short I have a function that reads a text file containing a secure string:

```
function Get-StoredCredential
{
    param([string]$username)
    <snip>..</snip>
    $Password = $credFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key
    $oCred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName, $Password)

    $oCred.GetType()
    $oCred    
}
```

Inside the function, $oCred.GetType() returns:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                                              
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                                              
True     True     PSCredential                             System.Object
```

However, outside the function calling it like so:

```
$a = Get-StoredCredential -UserName "john" -Verbose
$a.gettype()
```

Returns an object type:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                                              
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                                              
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

In the function where I want to use the credential object, I need to call .GetNetworkCredential().Password which has been stripped out of the object because of this apparent type change.

Any suggestions?

TIA.

P.S. PowerShell 5.0

**Update**

```
PS C:\> $a.Length
2

PS C:\> $a[0]

MYDOMAIN\john

PS C:\> $a[1]

UserName                         Password
--------                         --------
MYDOMAIN\john System.Security.SecureString

PS C:\> $a[2]
PS C:\>
```

Comment: What is `$a.Length` after running function? IMHO, problem in `<snip>..</snip>` part of your code.

Comment: $a.Length returns 2. <snip>..</snip> is just showing there's more stuff in the function. Irrelevant to the question.

Comment: If `$a.Length` returns 2, then it means that your function return 2 items. `PSCredential` object will be last one: `$a[1]`, but `$a[0]` is likely returned by *irrelevant* code.

Comment: Sorry, it returns 2 items, not 3. You answered before I could correct. Updated question with results.

Comment: Apologies, I understand you first comment about <snip>..</snip> now.

Comment: Remove the `GetType()` call from your function. That causes it to output a second object.

Answer (score 2):

It's your call to `$oCred.GetType()` that is the first object being returned. The Credential is the second. Just stop doing `$oCred.GetType()` because it's unnecessary. If you want the info, send it in the verbose stream:

```
$oCred.GetType() | Write-Verbose

# or

$oCred.GetType() | Out-String | Write-Verbose
```

Comment: ...yes, exactly, like I mentioned in my comment. :)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart yes, we submitted them right around the same time

Comment: @PetSerAl, you were right, it was an error in the irrelevant code. An uncommented variable. Thanks and sorry for being so...

Comment: I was using $oCred.GetType() to try and show the difference I was seeing. I wasn't actually using it. Doesn't matter now.